# cannot access remote file with lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I just created a lambda and have given it the default VPC, Security Group, and Subnets. Gave it a role which has `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`. Verified outbound rules show 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports and protocols. Verified that lambda.amazonaws.com is a trusted entity on the policy.

Gave it code that is this (which works locally):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("http://www.google.com/robots.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    robots, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", robots)
}
```

And I use the "test" function in lambda, and all I get for my troubles is:
`Get "http://www.google.com/robots.txt": dial tcp 172.217.1.196:80: i/o timeout`

I've tried looking through every AWS document on the subject, and it doesn't appear that I'm missing something, but maybe somebody else would know?

I wasn't originally trying to access the google robots.txt file, but after getting the same result no matter what I tried, I figured I would pull an example straight from the documentation to rule out anything I'm doing. At least I know my code is executing, otherwise we wouldn't get this far. Any ideas at all for what to try?

Comment: If you use `https://www.google.com/robots.txt` instead does it work?  I'm wondering if redirects are not working for you.

Comment: 2020/08/07 20:27:25 Get "https://www.google.com/robots.txt": dial tcp 172.217.1.196:443: i/o timeout

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I overlooked in here is the subnets need a public NAT gateway… not an internet gateway. Once we added those, it was able to reach outside the AWS walls and downloaded the needed files.

Comment: Is there a reason why you attached the AWS Lambda function to the VPC? If it is _not_ attached, then it automatically gets Internet access.